# how can delivry price in prestashop 1.6 vary depending on weight

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'm using prestashop 1.6
I want to know if prestashop allow me to display price of order that vary depending on weight or should I develop my own module to achieve my aim ?

Comment: Can you please clarify that you want to show the price for `different weight options available for particular product` or want to charge something depending on `weight of all products in an order`.

Comment: I want to  charge something depending on weight of all products in an order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup this directly from your PrestaShop Back office within Carriers options, no need to create your own module.

To do so just go to :

- Carrier > Edit / Add Carrier > Go to step 2 of carrier setup.
- Here you should see something like this: http://bit.ly/1AJQXZ9
- Setup as many carriers  by weight ranges as needed, an extra cost will be applied on order depending on order total weight

Hope this helps !

Regards,

Comment: thank you men. I found it but I forget to write answer.  You deserve reputation score ;)